# Function to merge pandas dataframes based on different keywords

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a function that creates a dataframe based on different lists of words that come up in a certain column of another dataframe.

In my example, I want a dataframe created on the basis of the words "chandos" and "electronics" coming up in the "description" column of the "uncategorised" dataframe.

The point of the function is that I want to be able to run this on different lists of words so I end up with different dataframes containing just the words I want.

```
words_Telephone = ["tfl", "electronics"] 
df_Telephone = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','description','paid out'])



def categorise(word_list, df_name):
    """ takes the denoted terms from the "uncategorised" df and puts it into new df"""
    for word in word_list:
        df_name = uncategorised[uncategorised['description'].str.contains(word)]
        return(df_name)

#apply the function    
categorise(words_Telephone, df_Telephone)
```

I am expecting a dataframe that contains:

```
d = {'date': {0: '05/04/2017',
1: '06/04/2017',
```

2: '08/04/2017',
   3: '08/04/2017',
   4: '08/04/2017',
   5: '10/04/2017',
   6: '10/04/2017',
   7: '10/04/2017'},
   'description': {0: 'tfl',
    1: 'tfl',
    2: 'tfl',
    3: 'tfl',
    4: 'ac electronics ',
    5: 'ac electronics ',},
   'index': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10},
   'paid out': {0: 3.0,
    1: 4.3,
    2: 6.1,
    3: 1.5,
    4: 16.39,
    5: 20.4,}}

Reproducible df:

```
d = {'date': {0: '05/04/2017',
  1: '06/04/2017',
  2: '06/04/2017',
  3: '08/04/2017',
  4: '08/04/2017',
  5: '08/04/2017',
  6: '10/04/2017',
  7: '10/04/2017',
  8: '10/04/2017'},
 'description': {0: 'tfl',
  1: 'mu subscription',
  2: 'tfl',
  3: 'tfl',
  4: 'tfl',
  5: 'ac electronics ',
  6: 'itunes',
  7: 'ac electronics ',
  8: 'google adwords'},
 'index': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10},
 'paid out': {0: 3.0,
  1: 16.9,
  2: 4.3,
  3: 6.1,
  4: 1.5,
  5: 16.39,
  6: 12.99,
  7: 20.4,
  8: 39.68}}
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
def categorise(word_list):
    """ takes the denoted terms from the "uncategorised" df and puts it into new df then deletes from the uncategorised df"""
    global uncategorised
    new_dfs = []
    for word in word_list:
        new_dfs.append(uncategorised[uncategorised['description'].str.contains(word)])
        uncategorised= uncategorised[ ~uncategorised['description'].str.contains(word)]

    return (uncategorised)
    return (pd.concat(new_dfs).reset_index())

#apply the function    
df_Telephone = categorise(words_Telephone)

df_Telephone
```

Comment: Can you please share your sample DatFrame as well and what is looking as an expected output ?

Comment: If you want to get the entire row when the `description` column is equal to an element in `words_Telephone` then you can do as follows: `df_name = uncategorised.loc[uncategorised['description'].isin(words_Telephone)]` .If not you give us some data and expected output.

Comment: Updated.

My issue is that I want to end up with a dateframe with the values of two or more different search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words_Telephone = ["tfl", "electronics"] 
original_df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict({'date': ['05/04/2017','06/04/2017','06/04/2017','08/04/2017','08/04/2017','08/04/2017','10/04/2017','10/04/2017','10/04/2017'], 'description': ['tfl','mu subscription','tfl','tfl','tfl','ac electronics','itunes','ac electronics','google adwords'], 'paid out' :[ 3.0,16.9, 4.3,6.1,1.5,16.39,12.99,20.4,39.68]})

def categorise(word_list, original_df):
    """ takes the denoted terms from the "uncategorised" df and puts it into new df"""
    new_dfs = []
    for word in word_list:
        new_dfs.append(original_df[original_df['description'].str.contains(word)])

    return pd.concat(new_dfs).reset_index()

#apply the function    
df_Telephone = categorise(words_Telephone, original_df)
print(df_Telephone)


         date     description  paid out
0  05/04/2017             tfl      3.00
1  06/04/2017             tfl      4.30
2  08/04/2017             tfl      6.10
3  08/04/2017             tfl      1.50
4  08/04/2017  ac electronics     16.39
5  10/04/2017  ac electronics     20.40
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand your code.

I get this error: IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0

I don't understand why this line is necessary: list_of_values = np.sort(df_Telephone['description'].unique())


All I want is to take words listed in [words_Telephone] to be searched in the description column of uncategorised and be put into the dateframe df_Telephone.

Comment: list_of_values is supposed to contain the desired values.  Sorry, but I guess I didn't mimic your notation well.  I've just edited the solution to reflect your specific example

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. You are defining df_Telephone explicitly.. this should be done programatically. That's the whole point of the script..

Comment: I guess I missed your naming convention completely.  I think I now just modified your original post to give you what you want.

Comment: return pd.concat(new_dfs).reset_index() 
returns an invalid syntax error. even when I put brackets around it

Comment: I am struggling to get this to delete the rows from the original df now. I have added this line so far:

        original_df.drop(original_df[original_df['description'].str.contains(word)])

Comment: to get the rest of the DataFrame you should do: 
original_df = original_df[ ~original_df['description'].str.contains(word)]

Comment: Thank you, although how do I get it to alter the dataframe outside the function (non-locally)?

Comment: Editing with complete solution. I also removed the argument for "original_df" as it was redundant. Thank you for your help.